# iFrame: using jQuery to add click event to button

Tags: jquery, html, button, iframe, click

I'm working on a brief quiz that is going to be built with an iFrame in HTML and JavaScript/jQuery. I've been trying to figure out why my buttons and onclick events aren't working.

Here's what I have in HTML:

```
<iframe id="iframe">

</iframe>
```

And JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function getDog() {
    alert("Dogs are great!");
  }

      var $iframe = $('#iframe');
      var $dogButton = "<button id=\'dog\'>Dog</button>";

      $iframe.contents().find("body").append("What is your favorite animal?");
      $iframe.contents().find("body").append($dogButton);
      document.getElementById("dog").addEventListener("click", getDog());
    })
```

For some reason this won't work in a snippet, so here's my CodePen: https://codepen.io/anfperez/pen/agRVKE

I know this is written in "old" JS, but I'm working with a legacy backend.

I haven't really worked with iFrames before. Can anyone give some suggestions on why this wouldn't be working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `$iframe.contents()[0].getElementById("dog").addEventListener("click", function() {
    getDog()
  });`

But this only works in iframes hosted in the same domain.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the dog button inside the Iframe contents, just like you have appended the button.

```
$iframe.contents().find(".dog").addEventListener("click", getDog());
```

**Note**: As said, it won't work with CORS (cross-origin). Only works if the iframe URL is in the same domain